# SSRS: Display changing Name per Machine

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I created this table here in SSRS:

[image]
[image]

I would like to show only when a Machine changes the ProductName not all the Format. in the picture above I would like to display only:                          *08.01.16  -  M102   - Roller
 11.01.16  -  M102   - Blank*

My QUery:

```
SELECT 
    c.Datum,
    c.Team,
    c.Name,
    c.Product,
    c.System

    FROM (
    Select 
intervaldate as Datum
,tsystem.Name as Name
,ProductName As Product
,teamname as Team
,SUM(GoodUnits)  / NULLIF(SUM(TheoreticalUnits) , 0.0)* 100 As System

from tCount 
where IntervalDate >= @StartDateTime AND IntervalDate <= @EndDateTime
and systemID in (Select SystemID from tSystem whereViewID in (21,25,6))     
group by intervaldate, teamName, tsystem.Name, ProductName
) c

inner join(
SELECT 
    sc.Name as Name

    FROM tCalendar sh
    INNER JOIN tSchedule sc ON (sc.ID = sh.ScheduleID)
    WHERE Scheduled != 0
) p ON p.Name = c.Name
```

I would like to display only this changes per machine.
Is it possible to display this in a table?

Comment: That query doesn't produce the output in your picture. How are you getting the data in your top picture?

Comment: So...  A little dirty: In your query, you could select the top 1 id where the timestamp is less than the current row's time range (ordering by the timestamp descending).  Then do a left join using that id, so that every row has the fields of its predecessor and you can filter for inequality right there.  Depending on the size of your dataset, that might be too inefficient or require you to filter before introducing the subquery.  But I've done that now and again with ad-hoc queries.

Comment: ok, first of all thank you for your answer but could you maybe explain it in detail